# saving graph in pdf or png scaling issue

Tags: r, pdf, plot, png

I am trying to save two of my q-plots (A and B) as pdf or png. For both plots, X and Y axis have the same units (distance in meter). Xlim and Ylim for the two plots are different.I would like that the representation of 1m in plot A is equal to 1m in plot B when I display the pdf files.

in my case:

```
xlim.A=c(3,6)
ylim.A=c(-.2,1.5)
xlim.B=c(10,11)
ylim.B=c(0,4)
x <- seq(from=xlim.A[1],to=xlim.A[2],length.out=100)
y <- seq(from=ylim.A[1],to=ylim.A[2],length.out=100)
A <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

x <- seq(from=xlim.B[1],to=xlim.B[2],length.out=100)
y <- seq(from=ylim.B[1],to=ylim.B[2],length.out=100)
B <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)    

require(ggplot2)

my.plot.A <- qplot(A$x,A$y,asp=(ylim.A[2]-ylim.A[1])/(xlim.A[2]-xlim.A[1]),xlab="Distance (m)",
ylab="Elevation (m)")
my.plot.B <- qplot(B$x,B$y,asp=(ylim.B[2]-ylim.B[1])/(xlim.B[2]-xlim.B[1]),xlab="Distance (m)",
ylab="Elevation (m)")
ggsave("plot_A.pdf",plot=my.plot.A,scale=1)
ggsave("plot_B.pdf",plot=my.plot.B,scale=1)
```

By doing this, the equivalent distance for 1m in the first file is not equivalent to 1m in the second file. How can I make them equal?
Thanks

Comment: Why do they have to be in separate files? Putting both graphs in the same image via faceting would be simpler, and would ensure common scales.

Comment: @joran, limits on both plots are different, but the unit is the same. And I still struggle organizing my data in a way facetting would work for this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using asp, you are forcing the two graphs to have different scales. Matching them up in printed form will be very difficult.

Instead, you can use larger graphs and then crop as necessary, thus ensuring the correct scale.

```
xscale <- c(min(xlim.A[[1]], xlim.B[[1]]), max(xlim.A[[2]], xlim.B[[2]]))
yscale <- c(min(ylim.A[[1]], ylim.B[[1]]), max(ylim.A[[2]], ylim.B[[2]]))

sameScale <- coord_cartesian(xlim=xscale, ylim=yscale)

plotA <- qplot(A$x,A$y) + sameScale
plotB <- qplot(B$x,B$y) + sameScale
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How would you crop them? with R or an image editing software?

Comment: @user1367097, sorry for the slow response, just noticed the comment.  I would crop in any photo or document editor of choice.  If you're on a mac, `Preview` works just fine.  `Word` would even work as well